# Convert int to appropriate enum value based on the member's value

Tags: enums, d

I have an `enum` type and I would like to convert integer value to that type. This is not working:

```
enum Code
{
   OK = 200,
   FAILURE = 400
} 

auto c = to!Code("200");
```

but this is:

```
enum Code
{
   OK = 200,
   FAILURE = 400
} 

Code c = to!Code("OK");
```

It seems that `to!(T)` is doing conversion based on the enum member's name, and not on the value. So, I've tried this and it is working:

```
Code c = cast(CodeEnum)200;
```

Is this a valid (and only) way to do this conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the issue is somewhere else. This behaves as expected with DMD 2.064 (tested on DPaste)

```
import std.conv;
import std.stdio;

enum Code
{
   OK = 200,
   FAILURE = 400
} 

void main()
{
    auto c = to!Code(200);
    writeln(c);
}
```

[(link for convenience)](http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/54e1ada98ed6)

Are you sure that the underlying types for `Code` and the argument to `to!Code` are the same in your case? That is a requirement for the conversion.

Comment: Yeah, the issue was somewhere else! I was effectively executing `to!Code("200");` which did the lookup by string! Thanks!